# Looking for software/device to track members of a riding group

Tags: open-source, maps, device-driver

We are a group of bike rider; whenever we go on a trip its been a little difficult to manage the location of all riders.

Like If somebody left behind how can we find exact location of the bike.

Do we have any **Device/Software** by which we can continues track each others location?

**Note:** If any external device is available let us know we are ready to buy this.

Location: if I have to be precise - **India**

Any software based on Android, IOS or window will be helpful.

Comment: If you need recommendations for devices, this is off-topic here. You could [edit] your question to ask if there’s software e.g. for smartphones (iOS, Android, …), if that would work for you.

Comment: On Android, [Glympse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=glympse) comes to mind (you decide who can see your position). For alternatives on Android, see my list on [Location Sharing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_565).